# Pivot in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert following rows:

table {name,col} values{(x,value1), 
(x ,    value2) 
(x ,    value3)
(x ,    value2) 
(x ,    value3)
(y ,    value1) 
(y ,    value3)
(y ,    value3)
(z ,    value1)}

into following columns:
{name ,value1, value2 , value3} values{(x,1,2, 2), (y, 1, 0 , 2)(z, 1, 0 , 0)}
I use the following code but it doesn't know crosstab:

SELECT * FROM crosstab
(
'SELECT name , col, count(col)
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
order by name
)
AS (name text, value1 integer, value2 integer, value3 integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 1):

This line should be added before the code:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;